# Element-wise median of a lot of matrices, python pandas

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix, pandas, median

I have a dictionary of matrices.

The dictionary is called dict.

```
dict[location]
```

returns a square n x n correlation dataframe for that location.

```
locations
```

is the list of all locations.  (Keys in the dictionary).

I want to essentially make a list of every i,j component in a dataframe across keys and take the median of all of those.  You can think of this as stacking the matrices on top of each other and taking the median value for each i,j element.  I hope I explained this clearly enough.

I was wondering if there is a clever way to do this.  I would like to avoid making the list of n(n+1)/2 unique i,jth pairs and then taking the medians, then putting them back in their proper place in the final median matrix (dataframe).

Comment: You could use numpy.median on a single (3D) array made by stacking all the matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to work well and efficiently.

```
numpy.median(dict.values(),axis=0)
```

In general, the median requires all of the data in memory, unless you only want an estimate. Therefore, for a large amount of data, you'll have to work in chunks:

```
numpy.median( [m[0:10,0:10], for m in dict.values()], axis=0)
```

Comment: Hmm, I have 117 keys and each matrix is 76 x 76.  Dict.values() works, but when I use numpy.median, the computer crashes.

Comment: Finally, it finished loading: this was the error:  ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Comment: I thought you had a dictionary, not a dataframe.

Comment: That's the error though, it actually spits out like 1000 lines of errors. The matrices have some NANs, could that be it?

Comment: Ah yes, you cannot have a median when some values are NaN; unless of course you want a median of all the non-NaN values.

Comment: Is there a way to specify I want only the non-Nan values?

Comment: You can with pandas' Series.median().

Comment: @svenkatesh  that only works for median of a series, right?  I need median of a list of matrices.