# Pandas: Take the median accross multiple dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This question was asked before [on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469470/element-wise-median-of-a-lot-of-matrices-python-pandas), but the suggested solution does not work for me. I have multiple dataframes, all with the same columns and index that looks like the one below:

```
       E          F          H          I  
row                                                                     
CE     17.917153 10.875160   9.970251  12.255511   
CF     9.780500  16.261098  10.021619   9.447307   
CH     12.293967 10.608844  10.870527  17.720458   
CI     9.967815  11.181572  17.550371  10.845565
```

Across all the dataframes, I want to take the median of each *i,j* element.

If I try for instance, storing all my dataframes in a dictionary called `dict` and do:

```
np.median(dict.values(), axis=0)
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469470/element-wise-median-of-a-lot-of-matrices-python-pandas), I get as an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What is the correct way to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "pandy" way to do this is to create a [panel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel). For example:

```
>>> l = [df1, df2, df3, ...]
>>> panel = pd.Panel({i: df for i, df in enumerate(l)})
>>> panel
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 4 (major_axis) x 4 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 0 to 1
Major_axis axis: 0 to 3
Minor_axis axis: 0 to 3
```

Now to calculate the median just do:

```
panel.median(axis=0)
```

Comment: Oh great! Interesting, I didn't know the `panel` function.

Comment: @Plug4, A panel is like a 3D collection of 2D dataframes. I added a link to my answer.